# Python EXE file creation

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I have this code which i need to create it as a python exe file, where in user has to click the workflow done.

My Sample Project

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sys
import csv

path = os.getcwd()

v1 = pd.read_csv(r"path\V1.tsv", delimiter = '\t')

v1.to_csv(r"path\v2.csv", index=False)
```

I used Pyinstaller to create a .exe file but it didnt help me achieve what I want. Can some one suggest me?

Comment: could you please tell what error occured?

Comment: Are you aware that you don't use your variable `path` in `r"path\V1.tsv"`? Does your program run if you start it as a script?

Comment: Have your tried using the --onefile flag to specify that you only want 1 exe file to be created for that script.

Comment: "It didn't help me achieve what I want."  What is it that you want?  How can we possibly help you if we don't know what didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what disappointed you about PyInstaller, (speed? size? too many files in directory?), you may either want to try:

- PyInstaller's `--onefile` flag, which will compile everything into one .exe file but will take forever to run
- [cx_Freeze](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html). This can generate .exe files like PyInstaller, though performance won't be much better. What I find most useful is to compile the files into an installer by calling `py setup.py bdist_msi` (Windows) or `py setup.py bdist_dmg` (Linux). People can use the installer to add the .exe to their machines. Installer-created .exe files will run very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried using the `--onefile` flag to specify that you only want 1 exe file to be created for that script.

For example use the cmd: `pyinstaller --onefile file_name.py`

If this does not help can you specify the issue that is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you can install pyinstaller using the command `pip install pyinstaller`.

Once the installation is successful, you can run the command `pyinstaller --onefile your_script_name.py`